# Not updating data at view using redux / apollo graphql

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo

When add/edit/delete record then not showing updated data at dashboard list page. Also not working `this.props.data.refetch();` whenever data coming in `this.props.data`. But `this.props.data.refetch()` getting {}. 
I am using `Material UI Table` to show records.

My delete function on `dashboardContainerPage` is like below code. Record deleted but not showing at dashboard without page refresh.

```
handleDelete(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Remove function called")
    const id = event.currentTarget.id;
    //console.log("===============",event.target);
    this.props.mutate({variables: { id }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        this.props.router.replace('/');
        console.log("Query respond")
        this.props.data.refetch();
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.data.refetch()));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625812/updatequeries-after-graphql-mutation-not-working-with-the-apollo-client/42629412#42629412)

Comment: Bhavya, I have clonned this project from https://github.com/jferrettiboke/react-auth-app-example . And in this also not showing new added records at dashboard. When user signup 2nd time. After page refresh user can see new added record.