# How do I update the Apollo data store/cache from a mutation query, the update option doesn't seem to trigger

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a higher order component in my react native application that retrieves a Profile.  When I call an "add follower" mutation, I want it to update the Profile to reflect the new follower in it's followers collection.  How do I trigger the update to the store manually.  I could refetch the entire profile object but would prefer to just do the insertion client-side without a network refetch.  Currently, when I trigger the mutation, the Profile doesn't reflect the change in the screen.

It looks like I should be using the `update` option but it doesn't seem to work for me with my named mutations.  http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-mutations.html#graphql-mutation-options-update

```
const getUserQuery = gql`
 query getUserQuery($userId:ID!) {
    User(id:$userId) {
      id
      username
      headline
      photo
      followers {
        id
        username
        thumbnail
      }
    }
 }
`;
...

const followUserMutation = gql`
  mutation followUser($followingUserId: ID!, $followersUserId: ID!) {
    addToUserFollowing(followingUserId: $followingUserId, followersUserId: $followersUserId) {
      followersUser {
        id
        username
        thumbnail
      }
    }
  }`;
...

@graphql(getUserQuery)
@graphql(followUserMutation, { name: 'follow' })
@graphql(unfollowUserMutation, { name: 'unfollow' })
export default class MyProfileScreen extends Component Profile

...

  this.props.follow({
    variables,
    update: (store, { data: { followersUser } }) => {
      //this update never seems to get called
      console.log('this never triggers here');
      const newData = store.readQuery({ getUserQuery });
      newData.followers.push(followersUser);
      store.writeQuery({ getUserQuery, newData });
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Just realised that you need to add the update to the graphql definition of the mutation.

EDIT 2: @MonkeyBonkey found out that you have to add the variables in the read query function

```js
@graphql(getUserQuery)
@graphql(followUserMutation, {
  name: 'follow',
  options: {
    update: (store, { data: { followersUser } }) => {

       console.log('this never triggers here');
       const newData = store.readQuery({query:getUserQuery, variables});
       newData.followers.push(followersUser);
       store.writeQuery({ getUserQuery, newData });
     }
  },
});
@graphql(unfollowUserMutation, {
  name: 'unfollow'
})
export default class MyProfileScreen extends Component Profile

  ...

  this.props.follow({
      variables: { .... },
    );
```

I suggest you update the store using the `updateQueries` functionality [link](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#updateQueries).

See for example this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625812/updatequeries-after-graphql-mutation-not-working-with-the-apollo-client/42629412#42629412)

You could use `compose` to add the mutation to the component. Inside the mutation you do not need to call `client.mutate`. You just call the mutation on the follow user click.

It might also be possible to let apollo handle the update for you. If you change the mutation response a little bit that you add the following users to the followed user and add the `dataIdFromObject` functionality. [link](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#normalization)

Comment: According to the docs - it says that updateQueries are deprecated and to use update instead http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#updateQueries, I tried using the update option but it doesn't seem to trigger the update - I'll update the question with that code snippet

Comment: Did you console.log(newData). One thing, you maybe have to name the query for the `readQuery` to be able to find it. `const getUserQuery = gql'query getUserQuery {....}`

Comment: I named the readquery - but still no triggering of the update function - I console.log the first line but it doesn't get called - I'll update the question with the console.log and your suggestion to name the query

Comment: Updated my answer. I think you have to add the update definition in the graphQL definition. Maybe it is not working like this but its the way to go

Comment: I tried it in the graphql definition like in your sample but it still doesn't seem to trigger,  I'm using apollo-client version 1.2.2 and react-apollo 1.2.0

Comment: edited the code snippet. I think you need to add another object with options. Like [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-mutations.html#graphql-mutation-options-update). You might have to change the variable assignment etc.

Comment: getting there - now it's firing the update function but I'm getting an error `Cannot read 'kind' of undefined' at  `const newData = store.readQuery({ getUserQuery });`  Do I need to pass varialbes into the readQuery?  Also, the data that comes back looks like its wrapped within an object with _type and other info, should I push `followersUser.followersUser` instead of just `followersUser` because of that?

Comment: ok - found fix - `store.readQuery({query:getUserQuery, variables});` is the syntax that will work - if you update the answer with that I'll accept