# Update method in mutation not running

Tags: caching, apollo, react-apollo

I have the following component that mutates data. Apollo provides functionality to update the store automatically. I would like to control the way the data is added to the store using the [update](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#directAccess) function. The documentation is straightforward enough, but I can't get it working. What is wrong in the code below that would prevent the `console.log` from printing.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { graphql, gql, compose } from 'react-apollo';
import { personCodeSelector } from '../../selectors/auth';
import UploadBankStatement from '../../components/eftFileUploads/UploadBankStatement.jsx';

const createEftFileUpload = gql`mutation createEftFileUpload(
  $bankAccountCode: String!,
  $uploadInput: UploadInput!,
  $uploadedByPersonCode: String!) {
    createEftFileUpload(
      bankAccountCode: $bankAccountCode,
      uploadInput: $uploadInput,
      uploadedByPersonCode: $uploadedByPersonCode) {
          id
          bankAccountCode
          fileName
          numberOfProcessedItems
          numberOfUnallocatedItems
          createdAt
          status
        }
      }`;

const mutationConfig = {
  props: ({ ownProps, mutate }) => ({
    createEftFileUpload: (bankAccountCode, uploadInput) => {

      return mutate({
        variables: {
          bankAccountCode,
          uploadInput,
          uploadedByPersonCode: ownProps.personCode
        },
        update: (store, something) => {
          console.log("ping");
          console.log(store, something);
          },
      });
    }
  })
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    personCode: personCodeSelector(state)
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  graphql(createEftFileUpload, mutationConfig)
)(UploadBankStatement);
```

Note I have found a couple of similar [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011081/how-do-i-update-the-apollo-data-store-cache-from-a-mutation-query-the-update-op), but it doesn't seem to shed any light on my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server restart fix my issue. Not sure why this was required with hot-reloading. The code was correct.